MariaDB 11 (also MySQL) "CLI ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it" when connecting to MariaDB 10.4
When I try to connect to a server using MariaDB 11's mariadb/mysql cli commands, I get the error "ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it" when connecting to a mariadb 10.4 server
Tried connecting to the server using the normal host, port and password options


This can be solved by adding the --skip_ssl parameter.

That definitely works.
If you don't want to type --skip-ssl on the command line every time, you can instead add this to ${HOME}/.my.cnf:
[client]
skip-ssl = true


If you wanted to skip SSL on the client, then the skip-ssl settings should go under the [client] section. According to MariaDB docs: [mysql] - Options read by mysql, which includes both MariaDB Server and MySQL Server.

It doesn't have any effect whatsoever with MariaDB 11.7

Since MariaDB Version 10.10.1 the MariaDB command line client requires a secure connection and enables the --ssl option by default. See also MDEV-27105
According to the error message, the server doesn't support secure TLS/SSL connections.
Possible solutions:

skip secure connections by starting the command line client with option --ssl=0.
Enable TLS on your database server.
Upgrade your database server (10.4 reached end of life): Since version MariaDB 11.4 server always starts with TLS support (if you didn't configure TLS, the server will do that automatically)


This can be solved by adding the --skip_ssl parameter. After that, the connection works.
P.S. Answering my own question because I didn't find an answer online earlier.

The other way is to setup TLS on MariaDB server.
